# (Robo-review) Can my edit please be approved?

Tags: discussion

https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/962137

The question is quite old and it has been closed a long time ago.  Therefore, the edits will NOT push the post into the queue.  The OP rejected it for a completely wrong reason.

Can someone please override this to approved?

Comment: 1) it obviously wasn't a "robo-review" as the reject reason is custom and OP took the time to write it. Robo reviews are generally accepting everything regardless. This is definitely not that. 2) what is the point in editing a closed question? Why does it ***need*** to be corrected? Are there better places to spend your time on than closed questions? OP doesn't want it edited in that way, so why do we need to force it for the sake of one small number difference and a spelling error?

Comment: "The question is quite old and has been closed a long time ago" and "edits will NOT push the post into the queue" so what exactly is the point of editing it in the first place if not to bring it to a state where it can be reopened?

Comment: The edit seems **trivial** and specifically goes against the intent of the author’s original question.  No; We are not going to overwrite the author in a case like this.  Your edit doesn’t improve the quality of the quest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question is quite old and it has been closed a long time ago. Therefore, the edits will NOT push the post into the queue. The OP rejected it for a completely wrong reason.

So it appears you proposed a trivial edit.  Trivial edits should be rejected.  Your edit doesn’t resolve the fact that many answers to the author’s question would be highly opinionated.

> Can someone please override this to approved

The author themselves, an active user, rejected your trivial edit to their question.  The edit seems trivial and specifically goes against the intent of the author’s original question.

**No;** We are not going to overwrite the author in a case like this. Your edit doesn’t improve the quality of the question.

Comment: I rejected the most recent [edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/964770) proposal for the same reason.